# how does one create an XLIFF file

Tags: text-editors, translation

I see lots of info and tutes on how to use some XLIFF translators, and how to create .po files, but how do I create an XLIFF file?

It seems XLIFF editors allow you to open and translate an XLIFF file, but not create one.

Be gentle, I'm just a programmer. I don't know about human languages... :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try [`po2xliff`](http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/translate-toolkit/en/latest/commands/xliff2po.html) from the [Translate Toolkit](http://toolkit.translatehouse.org/), which allows to convert easy-to-edit po files to xliff format.

Comment: what is a "po" file?